# Mysql unique constraint broken, production table contains multiple rows with same id

Tags: mysql

I have a table (sale_orders) with a unique constraint on the column nonce_id. Somehow 144* (!) rows have the same nonce_id as another row.

Here is an example of one of them:

`` SELECT id, nonce_id  FROM `sale_orders` WHERE `nonce_id` LIKE '%07JCEOIU4UCg7T1PZkMK4kRDuO2TO3BazawCs1y9jECe6paPHtVKXjDbAKm7OHek%' ORDER BY `nonce_id`  ASC ``

[Result query with like and double %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVlwG.png)

If I run a select with "=" instead of "LIKE", it only returns the first row

`` SELECT id, nonce_id  FROM `sale_orders` WHERE `nonce_id` = '07JCEOIU4UCg7T1PZkMK4kRDuO2TO3BazawCs1y9jECe6paPHtVKXjDbAKm7OHek' ORDER BY `nonce_id`  ASC ``

[Result query with =](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RPex.png)

I've checked and this is not an issue with (invisible) control characters or whitespacing or anything of the likes. The CHAR_LENGTH() is the same, the HEX() is the same.

This is the relevant sql-dump:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Gegenereerd op: 27 aug 2020 om 16:04
-- Serverversie: 10.2.31-MariaDB
-- PHP-versie: 7.2.29

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `[REDACTED]`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `sale_orders`
--

CREATE TABLE `sale_orders` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `sale_order_counter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nonce_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sale_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `menu_item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price_vati` decimal(30,15) NOT NULL,
  `vat_rate` decimal(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `sale_orders`
--

INSERT INTO `sale_orders` (`id`, `sale_order_counter`, `nonce_id`, `sale_id`, `menu_item_id`, `datetime`, `name`, `price_vati`, `vat_rate`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at`) VALUES
(464546, 14472, '07JCEOIU4UCg7T1PZkMK4kRDuO2TO3BazawCs1y9jECe6paPHtVKXjDbAKm7OHek', 160987, 294, '2020-08-24 12:29:14', '[REDACTED]', '3.600000000000000', '6.000', '2020-08-24 10:29:33', '2020-08-24 10:29:34', NULL),
(464548, 14472, '07JCEOIU4UCg7T1PZkMK4kRDuO2TO3BazawCs1y9jECe6paPHtVKXjDbAKm7OHek', 160987, 294, '2020-08-24 12:29:14', '[REDACTED]', '3.600000000000000', '6.000', '2020-08-24 10:29:34', '2020-08-24 10:30:23', '2020-08-24 10:30:23');

--
-- Indexen voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- Indexen voor tabel `sale_orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `sale_orders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `sale_orders_nonce_id_unique` (`nonce_id`),
  ADD KEY `sale_orders_sale_id_index` (`sale_id`),
  ADD KEY `sale_orders_menu_item_id_index` (`menu_item_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor een tabel `sale_orders`
--
ALTER TABLE `sale_orders`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=473472;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

However, importing this dump in another database fails exactly because of the UNIQUE constraint violation. Which is exactly why those two rows should have never existed togheter in the first place.

I'm absolutely puzzled as to how this happened.

(*) => I did `SELECT nonce_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM sale_orders GROUP BY nonce_id HAVING cnt > 1;`  and it returned 144 results

Comment: I'm puzzled too, your alter table should fail - and does when I run the published code. btw 'Noun. nonce (plural nonces) (Britain, slang, derogatory, prisons) A sex offender, especially one who is guilty of sexual offences against children.'- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonce

Comment: Your code works as expected see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4pKxNzJncK9Jf9cwk5y5hM/0 perhaps you inserted prior to ALTERing.

Comment: @P.Salmon Nope. Constraint was there from the beginning. And even if it wasn't, I wouldn't have been able to create the constraint with already existing rows that violate it. If it was just one row I would have assumed a Cosmic Ray bitflip or something but there are 144 of them...

Comment: nonce_id seems like an unfortunate name for a column.